# How to fit SVG image inside browser window both horizontally and vertically?

Tags: css, svg, responsive

I have an SVG image that I'd like to completely fit in the viewport without scrolling in either direction. The image is dynamically created so it might be wide and short, square, or tall and narrow.

I've got it to resize so it is always the width of the viewport, but I don't know if there is a HTML/CSS-only way to make sure it doesn't scroll vertically.

Here is my code to make the image responsive horizontally:

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="paper"
    style="padding-bottom: 111.981%;">
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      role="img"
      viewBox="0 0 792.0135606084274 886.9085000000002"
      preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
      <title>My Image</title>
      <path>etc...</path>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>

.paper {
    display: inline-block; 
    position: relative; 
    width: 100%; 
    vertical-align: middle; 
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: calc(100vh - 100px); // added in edit
}

.paper svg {
    overflow: hidden; 
    position: absolute; 
    display: inline-block; 
    top: 0px; 
    left: 0px;
    max-height: calc(100vh - 100px); // added in edit
}
```

(The `padding-bottom` and the `viewBox` is calculated when the SVG is completed.)

The only solution I can think of is to handle the resize event in JS and set a `max-width` on the `container` `div`. I'd like a CSS solution, though.

EDIT:
I added `max-height` and that has gotten me really close. The only problem is that the total size of the "paper" element doesn't change, so everything under it gets pushed down. If I change the paper's `padding-bottom` style by hand I can fix it, so now I'm trying to figure out how I can set it differently.

EDIT 2:
There is also a problem that when the `max-height` element kicks in, the visual width of the SVG changes, but it isn't reflected in the DOM. That means that adding something like this to `paper`: `background: green; border: 1px solid black;` no longer works, and `paper` is no longer centered horizontally.

EDIT 3:
What I'm trying to achieve is to put an SVG image that is generated dynamically so that it fits in a particular DIV without needing scrollbars. It should fit as large as possible. For an example, if you go to an image preview application, there is often a menu setting "Zoom to Fit". If the image is either too wide or too tall it is shrunk, if there is extra space it is expanded.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cgvcay5h/ or https://jsfiddle.net/dr1pa79k/

Comment: Wow, at first glance that looks great! I'm done for the day but I'll evaluate tomorrow. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: I suggest you edit the question and add your actually have a toolbar header.